# How to save a character into char array

Tags: c++

So i would like to know how to save characters in a char array. something like this.

---

```
int const l=100;
char a[l];
char b[l]
cin.getline(a,l);
int d;
d=strlen (a);
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{
  if(a[i]=='a')
  {do something so i can save  only the items that match the 
  criteria in the new char array}
```

I don't know if there is a function to do this or even how i should approach it .

Comment: Just use `std::copy_if`, or `std::remove_if` if you don't need `a` for something else.

Comment: @chris: I doubt that a beginner can use it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, A few examples and explanations and maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you *really* write in C++, avoid arrays. They are tougher to handle than objects really created for array or string handling, such as `std::string`.

Try this one:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::string s, s1;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a')
            s1.push_back(s[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "Processed string: " << s1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help if you don't use STL:

```
int j = 0; // index for b. An array will be filled from the zero element
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 'a') // or any filter criter
    {
        b[j] = a[i];
        ++j;
    }
}
b[j] = '\0';
```

With STL (and C++11):

```
auto it = std::copy_if(&a[0], &a[d], &b[0], [](char c){ return c == 'a'; });
*it = '\0';
```